# Find $\det(A)$ of Matrix and condition on a and b

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $$
        A=\begin{bmatrix}
        a & b & 1 \\
        b & 1 & b \\
        1 & a & a \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
Find $\det(A)$ in terms of $a$ and $b$, and write down the condition on $a$ and $b$ when $A$ is invertible. Simplify your answers.

I manage to find $\det(A)$ to be $a^2(1-b) + b^2(1-a) + ab -1$

For $A$ to be invertible $\det(A)$ cannot be equal to $0$, but I can't solve this equation for the condition of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Should the $(3, 2)$ entry be $b$ instead of $a$?

Comment: It should factor.  To get you started, what happens if $a=1$?  What happens if $b=1$?  Apply polynomial long division and write it in the form as a product of linear factors.  (*Notice, you could see these would cause a problem before even looking at the determinant since $a=1$ would imply the first and third columns are identical, while $b=1$ would imply the second and third columns are identical*)

Comment: @Travis, I don't see any reason to expect that to be the case.  The problem is routine even without that change.

Comment: @Travis The (3, 2) entry is a

Comment: @JMoravitz In fact, it's even easier as written in that the determinant factors into linear, real polynomials this way. I asked rather because the matrix is almost symmetrical as written, which suggested the possibility of a typo.

Comment: @JMoravitz so the answer will be a !=  1 and b != 1. As that condition will result in two rows or column being similar. In fact, all the row and cols will be the same.

Comment: @Q.Bry there is one more condition that will cause the determinant to be zero that you haven't found yet.

Comment: @JMoravitz a=0 and b=1, a=1 and b = 0

Comment: I would like to note that you should try to use tricks to get your determinant factored already when you are calculating it. For example, every column in your matrix consists of one a, one b and one 1. This should help you get one factor by simple row-operations.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly found the determinant.

Expanding it out, we have $\det(A) = -a^2b + a^2 - ab^2+ab+b^2-1$

In the case that $a=1$, this is $-b+1-b^2+b+b^2-1=0$

This implies that $(a-1)\mid \det(A)$

Similarly, if $b=1$ we have $\det(A)=-a^2+a^2-a+a+1-1=0$, so also $(b-1)\mid \det(A)$

Since $\gcd((a-1),(b-1))=1$ this implies that $(ab-a-b+1)\mid \det(A)$

Applying polynomial long division, we arrive at the factorization:

> $\det(A) = -(a-1)(b-1)(a+b+1)$

Which implies that $A$ is invertible if and only if:

> $a\neq 1$ and $b\neq 1$ and $a+b\neq -1$

which is equivalent to saying

> $A$ is not invertible if and only if $a=1$ or $b=1$ or $a+b=-1$

As mentioned above, the first two conditions could be spotted by inspection by noting that it would cause the first and third columns or the second and third columns to be identical respectively which implies a zero determinant.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the polynomial that you given is correct, you can find those conditions as follows:

$$f(a,b) = a^2(1-b) + b^2(1-a) + ab - 1$$ It can also be expressed as:
$$ f(a,b) = (1-b)(a^2+ab+b+1) $$

So, $f(a,b)=0$ implies either $b=1$ or $a^2+ab+b+1=0 \rightarrow b=(-a^2-1)/(a+1)$.